# How to prove a bound function for a sequence of numbers?

Tags: recurrence-relation, loop-invariants

Let $G_n$ be defined by

$$G_n = \begin{cases} 1 & n=0 \\ 
2 & n = 1 \\ 
3 & n = 2 \\ 
4 & n = 3 \\
2G_{n-1}-2G_{n-3}+G_{n-4} & n\geq4
\end{cases}$$

How can I prove that $f(n) = n$ is a bound function (or loop variant) for the above sequence?

Comment: Have you tried computing $G_5$? $G_6$? $G_7$ $G_8$? $G_9$? What can you observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tried, you will find that 
$$\begin{aligned}
G_5&=6\\
G_6&=7\\
G_7&=8\\
G_8&=9\\
G_9&=10.\\
\end{aligned}$$

By now, you should have probably guessed that $G_{n}=n+1$. Now you can try proving it, using induction on $n$.

Once that formula has been proved, $f(n)=n$ is of course a lower bound for $G_n$.